# Hash routing with aviator

Tags: javascript, routes

I am curious why the code in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4s0pb6d/3/) does not work.

I am trying to setup [Aviator router](https://github.com/swipely/aviator/issues/46) with hash routing.

When I click the button the hash changes successful but the function `handleOutlineRoute` never gets called.

Here is my javascript:

```
class Application {

  init() {
    this.configureRouter()
    this.setupRoutes()
    this.dispatch()
  }

  configureRouter() {
    Aviator.pushStateEnabled = false
  }

  dispatch() {
    Aviator.dispatch()
  }

  setupRoutes() {
    Aviator.setRoutes({
        '/': {
        target: this,
        '/': 'handleWelcomeRoute',
        '/outline': 'handleOutlineRoute'
      }
    })
  }

  handleWelcomeRoute() {
    alert('welcome')
  }

  handleOutlineRoute() {
    alert('outline')
  }

}

(function() {
  const app = new Application()
  app.init()
  $('a.nav').attr('href', `#${Aviator.hrefFor('/outline')}`)
})()
```

and HTML:

```
<a class="nav"> Click Me </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved when the additional level of nesting [is removed](https://jsfiddle.net/u4s0pb6d/4/) from route configuration.

```
Aviator.setRoutes({
    target: this,
    '/': 'handleWelcomeRoute',
    '/outline': 'handleOutlineRoute'
})
```

The library treats `/` as a terminal endpoint.